# Magento code changes in local don't work

Tags: magento, search

I'm trying to fix the Magento search issue where 'OR' is used for comparison of multiple search terms instead of 'AND'.

I've seen quite a number of suggestions on the web regarding how to fix this, and the general idea is as follows:

Copy
`app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/resource/Fulltext.php` to 
`app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/resource/Fulltext.php` and in the copy, change the instances of 'OR' to 'AND', where the SQL queries are built.

However, my changes don't seem to work as expected and what is even more confusing is that the `prepareResult()` method (which is where the SQL changes above are made)  doesn't even seem to run at all when searches are done. I've tested this by putting some debugging code in the function.

I've used the same debug code to verify that the file gets loaded. But the debug code doesn't run when inserted at the `prepareResult()` function. (The debug code basically writes to a file on disk).

What am I missing here?

Kindly note that this is not so much about the right way to accomplish the end goal of fixing Magento search. I'm aware it's best done via an extension. I'd just like to figure out why  `prepareResult()` isn't being called as expected.

Comment: First check whether compiler mode is on or off. Also check search configuration details.

Comment: Compilation is turned off. I've also tried all three search types (Like, Fulltext and Combined (Like and fulltext). In all cases the `prepareResult()` function doesn't run.

Comment: Whenever developing turn off all caches in _System > Cache Management._  Make sure you are searching for something that hasn't been searched before, so that it cannot be using old results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, caching is also disabled.